# return некоторых значений в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть функция:

```
def test():
    return '1','2','3'
```

`test()[0]` возвращает `'1'`, соответственно `test()[1]` вернет `'2'`

Как вернуть несколько значений? К примеру `'1'` и `'3'`

Comment: `v1, _, v3 = test()` ?

Comment: В return может быть много значений, из которых мне нужно только 2, к примеру, под каждое ненужное использовать `_` ? Никак этого избежать нельзя?

Comment: ну тогда либо два раза вызвать как в вопросе или: `ret = test(); v1 = ret[0]; v3 = ret[2]; del ret;`. Еще можно Numpy использовать - у него более продвинутое индексирование

Comment: Ладно, понял, спасибо. Думал можно указывать больше одного значения.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предлагаю варианты:

- Поиграться с оператором `*`:

  ```
  def test():
      return '1', '2', '3', '4', '5'

  a, *b, c = test()
  print(a, c)  # 1, 5
  print(b)  # ['2', '3', '4']

  a, *b, c, d = test()
  print(a, c, d)  # 1 4 5
  ```
- Использовать метод `operator.itemgetter`:

  ```
  from operator import itemgetter

  a, b, c = itemgetter(0, 1, 3)(test())
  print(a, b, c)  # 1 2 4

  a = itemgetter(3)(test())
  print(a)  # 4
  ```

  Его можно обернуть в функцию:

  ```
  def get_by_index(items, index):
      return itemgetter(*index)(items)    

  a, b, c = get_by_index(test(), [0, 1, 3])
  print(a, b, c)  # 1 2 4

  a = get_by_index(test(), [3])
  print(a)  # 4
  ```
- Или сделать функцию, в которой укажем какие индексы нужны:

  ```
  def get_by_index(items, index):
      return [x for i, x in enumerate(items) if i in index]

  a, b, c = get_by_index(test(), [0, 1, 3])
  print(a, b, c)  # 1 2 4
  ```

Comment: посмотрите на `operator.itemgetter`

Comment: @jfs, спасибо за подсказку :)

Comment: суть подсказки: не определяйте новую функцию get_by_index(), а используйте существующий itemgetter()

Comment: @jfs, ага, но функцию не буду убирать -- хуже от ее наличия не будет

Comment: вместо `itemgetter(3)(L)`, лучше писать `L[3]`.

Answer (score 3):

Numpy, Pandas, Xarray обладают продвинутым индексированием

```
In [4]: import numpy as np

In [5]: a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])

In [6]: a[[6, 0, 2, 7, 4]]
Out[6]: array([7, 1, 3, 8, 5])
```

но использовать их для такой элементарной задачи - это, по-моему, перебор

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант:

```
class SuperTuple(tuple):
    def __getitem__(self, x):
        if type(x) == list:
            return [tuple.__getitem__(self, y) for y in x]
        return tuple.__getitem__(self, x)


a = SuperTuple([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])

print(a[[3, 2, 1]])
print(a[1])

# -----
# [4, 3, 2]
# 2
```